# Azure CLI 2.0 Export Error

Tags: azure-cli

I have a resource group called log-rg. I want to generate a deployment script and tried using: az group export --name log-rg and I get: The schema of resource type 'Microsoft.EventGrid/topics' is not available. Resources of this type will not be exported to the template. This is the same error I get when I generate the same from the Azure portal as it informs me there are errors, but it still generates the script. I want to do the same from the command line using the above but it stops after the first error and does not generate any files. How can I make this command line az process continue and provide files like the portal does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue. You could check this [feedback](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/3889).

I test in my lab, I meet same issue. Even in my template, there are some resources in it, I could not export the template. We should give a feedback to Azure.

Another solution, you could use `az group deployment export`
 to export a template that not error in it.

Using `az group deployment list --resource-group` to list deployment name.

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az_group_deployment_export).